# Программа подсчета простых множителей С# с применением методов

Tags: c#

Подскажите, что не так в моем коде. "К" не хочет брать на себя значение функции. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете :-)

```
//12. Дано натуральное число N. Составить функцию, значение которой будет
//равно количеству различных простых множителей заданного числа.
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;

namespace LR7_Paskhin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {      
                int N; int k;
                k = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Введите N");
                N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int S = N;
                if (N > 1)
                {
                    Mnozhiteli(N,k);
                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Количество множителя числа {0}:{1}", N, k);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }

            
        }
        static int Mnozhiteli( int N,  int k)
        {  try
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",N);
                int i; 
                i = 1; // Множитель числа
                k = 0;    // Счетчик простых множителей
                while (i < N )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    if (N % i == 0)
                    {
                        ++i;
                    }
                    ++k;
                    Console.WriteLine(k);
                    if (i <=N)
                    { break; }
                }
                return k;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
        
          
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделайте k=Mnozhiteli(N,k); А еще лучше почитать про входные и выходные параметры. И функция Mnozhiteli(N,k) должна по любому возвращать значение.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве решения вашей задачи можно предложить следующий код:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введите N: ");
        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
        {
            if (number > 1)
            {
                var count = Mnozhiteli(number);
                Console.WriteLine($"Количество множителя числа {number}: {count}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("N должно быть больше 1");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введенное значение не является числом");
        }
    }

    private static int Mnozhiteli(int N)
    {
        var result = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            if (N % i == 0 && IsSimple(i))
            {
                result++;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает True, если число number является простым.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsSimple(int number)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return number != 1;
    }
```

Comment: Вы сами проверяли свой код? Он даёт то, о чем спрашивается в вопросе?

Comment: MBo, больше конкретики, пожалуйста. Код протестирован.

Comment: Пожалуйста - для 12 код даст 6, а нужно 2 (простые множители 2 и 3). Вероятно, Вы невнимательно прочитали задачу

Comment: Да, реально, спасибо. Я был невнимателен, добавил в код проверку на то, чтобы множители являлись простыми числами.

Comment: Единица не является простым числом

Comment: MBo, спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Я, кажется, знаю, что не так в Вашем коде:

1. Вы пишите:

```
 while (i < N )
 {
 ...
 if (i <=N){ break; } // Зачем тут это? У вас же while и так выйдет когда надо.
 }
```

2. В том же цикле, тут:

```
 while (i < N )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    if (N % i == 0)
                    {
                        ++i;
                    }
                    ++k;
}
```

Вы берете остаток от деления исходного числа на `i` и увеличиваете `i` на 1. То есть на 4 итерации `i = 4` **не простому** числу, а нужно найти простые множители.

3. Тот же код: Почему у Вас `k` прибавляется вне зависимости от условия прибавляется? В связке с ошибкой `2` Ваш счетчик будет считать не только `все` множители, а и каждый проход цикла while.

В общем, в коде есть ошибки. Я бы предложил такой алгоритм решения Вашей задачи:

1. Смотрим на `N` и принимаем его в качестве граничного числа.
2. Ищем все простые числа до граничного. Самый простой способ [решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), формируем из них массив делителей.
3. В цикле берем остаток от деления `N` на каждый элемент массива. Если остаток — ноль, то `++k`

Могу добавить код, но думаю Вы и сами сможете реализовать алгоритм.

Comment: @Michal_retrovich Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, поставьте галочку, чтобы закрыть вопрос. Посетите ознакомительный тур по сайту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour и справку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help